# Elasticsearch reboot, number_of_pending_tasks keeps increasing indefinitely

Tags: elasticsearch

I had to restart the master elasticsearch, the status was red, then after some time the status went yellow (primary shards get assigned).

Now when I'm doing the query `curl http://x.x.x.x/_cluster/health?pretty` I can see that **the "number_of_pending_tasks" keeps increasing (now it is at 200k)**

I had a look at the pending tasks and I can see that it is mainly this tasks that get buffered:

```
, {
    "insert_order" : 58176,
    "priority" : "NORMAL",
    "source" : "indices_store",
    "executing" : false,
    "time_in_queue_millis" : 619596,
    "time_in_queue" : "10.3m"
  },
```

In the meantime I get the error about a rejected execution due to the queue capacity:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsRejectedExecutionException: rejected execution (queue capacity 200) on org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler@34c87ed9
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Are there any indexing actions triggered from there? Must be in the code, nah?

Comment: I use Node.js software, but the software is not up and not linked to the database, this get increased by hiself

Comment: Is there the engine by `CURL` automatically indexing https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation?

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://www.loggly.com/blog/use-elasticsearch-pending-tasks-make-actionable-loggly/. Please keep me posted. I am still before my first Elastisearch project. %)P Thanks.

Comment: Once all shards have been assigned, 10 minutes later the number of pending tasks reduced a lot, I guees it's elasticsearch magic

Comment: Thanks, gets into my bag of tricks.